# WordPress Theme Development Widgets Problem

Tags: wordpress, themes

I have make widgets by using pup in WordPress , the widgets show in the dashboard widgets but not show in the customization page , in my customization page this lines show, HOW I SHOW MY WIDGETS IN MY THEME CUSTOMIZATION ?

Your theme has 10 other widget areas, but this particular page doesn’t display them.
You can navigate to other pages on your site while using the Customizer to view and edit the widgets displayed on those page

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're referring to widget areas not widgets. To display a widget area you need to add it in a template file (like header.php, footer.php, single.php)

```
if (  is_active_sidebar( 'your-widget-area' ) ){    
        dynamic_sidebar( 'your-widget-area' ); 
            }
```